# Get Values of array with reference to other array in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array `a = ["APP","COM", "REJ" , "COM APP"]` and `b = [23,54,56,24]`. A and B are of equal length. How to get all elements of array B, in which the values of array a contains VALUE as APP

here in the array a there is an `APP` in `APP` ,`COM APP` , how to `return [23, 24]` as an array.

Answer (score 5):

Use [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method along with [`String#indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) method.

```js
var a = ["APP", "COM", "REJ", "COM APP"],
  b = [23, 54, 56, 24],
  c = 'APP';


console.log(
  b.filter(function(v, i) {
    return a[i].indexOf(c) > -1;
  })
)
```

---

For exact word match then use [`RegExp#test`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) method with word boundary regex .

```js
var a = ["APP", "COM", "REJ", "COM APP"],
  b = [23, 54, 56, 24],
  c = /\bAPP\b/;


console.log(
  b.filter(function(v, i) {
    return c.test(a[i]);
  })
)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use tis code:

```
var a = ["APP", "COM", "REJ", "COM APP"],
b = [23, 54, 56, 24],
var find=[]
for(var key in b){
  if(a[key].indexOf('APP')!=-1)
    find.push(b[key])
}
console.log(find)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also do as follows;

```js
var a = ["APP","COM", "REJ" , "COM APP"],
    b = [23,54,56,24],
    r = b.reduce((p,c,i) => a[i].includes("APP") ? p.concat(c) : p ,[]);
console.log(r);
```